# CYTHON : Generating coverage for pyx file

Tags: code-coverage, cython

I am trying to generate code coverage report for a cython module, an d facing issues.

I have a simple c++ code : apple.h and **apple.cpp** files.
The cpp file is simple as :

```
using namespace std;
namespace mango {
    apple::apple(int key) {
            _key = key;
    };
    int apple::execute()
    {
            return _key*_key;
    };
}
```

I have written a basic cython code over this in "**cyApple.pyx**" :

```
# cython: linetrace=True
from libcpp.list cimport list as clist
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

cdef extern from "apple.h" namespace "mango" :
    cdef cppclass apple:
            apple(int)
            int execute()
cdef class pyApple:
    cdef apple* aa
    def __init__(self, number):
            self.aa = new apple(number)

    def  getSquare(self):
            return self.aa.execute()
```

My **setup.py** file :

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

compiler_directives = {}
define_macros = []

compiler_directives['profile'] = True
compiler_directives['linetrace'] = True
define_macros.append(('CYTHON_TRACE', '1'))

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
       "cyApple",
       sources=["cyApple.pyx", "apple.cpp"],
       define_macros=define_macros,
       language="c++",
  ), compiler_directives=compiler_directives))
```

This generates a proper library **cyApple.so**.
I have also written a simple **appletest.py** file to run test cases :

```
import cyApple, unittest
class APPLETests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
            temp = 5
            apple1 = cyApple.pyApple(temp)
            self.assertEqual(25, apple1.getSquare())
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(APPLETests)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite)
```

The test works fine.
**The problem is I need to get code coverage for my cyApple.pyx file**

When i run "coverage report -m"
I get the error and coverage for only my test file not pyx file.

```
cyApple.pyx   NotPython: Couldn't parse '/home/final/cyApple.pyx' as Python source: 'invalid syntax' at line 2
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------
appletest.py       8      1    88%   9
```

I tried to look online and get some help , so i added
**.coveragerc** file with contents as :

```
[run]
plugins = Cython.Coverage
```

On running "**coverage run appletest.py**" i get errors :

```
...
... 
...
ImportError: No module named Coverage
```

I want to generate simple code coverage report for my pyx file. How i can do it in a simple way ?

I reinstalled Cython-0.28.3.
Now on running "coverage run appletest.py"
 I am getting error :

```
test1 (__main__.APPLETests) ... Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is my **apple.h** file :

```
#include<iostream>
namespace mango {
class apple {
public:

    apple(int key);
    int execute();
private:
    int _key;
};
}
```

Comment: What version of Cython?

Comment: "Cython version 0.20.1post0"

Comment: can you provide the `apple.h` file? I believe it is the only missing file to run the example.

Comment: Did you rebuild everything?

Comment: I could just execute the project with no segmentation fault. Are cython and coverage installed with the same python that was used to build the code?

Comment: Can you also make sure that you have no failed compilation file (such as `apple.c`, for instance?).

Comment: i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DCYTHON_TRACE=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cyApple.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/cyApple.o
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DCYTHON_TRACE=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c apple.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/apple.o

Comment: c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/cyApple.o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/apple.o -o /home/arya/cython/final/cyApple.so

Comment: The compilation seems good to me, no errors..P.S. I have apple.cpp in place of .c, hope it has no different effect.

Comment: The apple.cpp is fine. I had an issue with failed build file while testing. I re-tested with Python 2 and Python 3, Cython 0.28.2 and 0.28.3, and the code run with no issue. To build, I use `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must update Cython. The [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html#enabling-coverage-analysis) states:

> Since Cython 0.23, line tracing (see above) also enables support for
>   coverage reporting with the coverage.py tool.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple helper script that:

1. Runs all cython files in the directory
2. Creates a linetrace version of cython code, but cleans up after execution, so this won't interfere with production versions.
3. Produces cython annotated report with line coverage, takes care of `.coveragerc` creation and all technical stuff
4. Works well with pyximport, no need to build setup.py and rebuild cython modules

#### Caveats

- It works only for linux (but it's doable to adapt it for another OS)
- Built for anaconda python

Project:
https://github.com/alexveden/cython_coverage_script

Source code:
https://github.com/alexveden/cython_coverage_script/blob/master/cy_test/tests/run_cython_coverage_annotations.py

Hopefully this helps anyone, because I spent an enormous amount of time to figure out how to deal with coverage under Cython. It's appeared not a trivial task because, Cython coverage plugin has issues with mapping .pyx paths and pyximport doesn't support coverage directives.